# XMLSignature defaults to RSA, how to also verify DSA curves for SSL signatures?

Tags: java, xml, cryptography

I am writing java code to take a canonicalised XML file which is signed by an SSL key of an approved party.

I am able to get the content and signature out of the file and even verify the signature if the signer uses an RSA key.

However, if an SSL signature was created with a DSA key, the XMLSignature object will fail with the following error:

> javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl

My code is as follows:

```
    SignatureCheck result = new SignatureCheck();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xml = dBuilder.parse(fileStream);
    xml.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    // Find Signature element
    NodeList nl = xml.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
    if (nl.getLength() == 0) return result;

    // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to unmarshal the
    // document containing the XMLSignature
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    // Create a DOMValidateContext and specify a KeyValue KeySelector
    // and document context
    DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new CertKeySelector(), nl.item(0));

    // unmarshal the XMLSignature
    XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

    // Validate the XMLSignature (generated above)
    result.isValid = signature.validate(valContext);
```

Comment: Do you have the `CertKeySelector` code? It may be forcing the RSA algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that actually XML signature does accept this curve, I was just comparing the wrong certificate (an ecdsa one against an RSA one).